# How to extract expected values from zelig simulation output

Tags: r

How do I extract expected values from zelig's simulation output? According to the package details it is in slot qi$ev but it comes up NULL for me. I've seen this question asked on other forums as well and no one has responded to any of those postings...perhaps there is a problem with the package?

Comment: can you share a reproducible example please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Zelig 5 you can extract expected values (and other quantities of interest) with the `getqi` method. If your model object is named `z.out` than `z.out$getqi(qi = "ev")` will extract expected values.

The `getqi` method is documented at http://docs.zeligproject.org/en/latest/getters.html.